# How to apply ads blocker to HTML content get by Java HttpClient GET request and parse by Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, ads

I am going to crawl newspaper, article. However I don't want ads. I want to apply ads block on top of my request (similar to browsing the web manually with ads block on, then save the HTML page without ads)

```
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
   .setDefaultRequestConfig(this.config)
   .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
   .setSSLContext(sslContext)
   .setConnectionManager(cm)
   .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
   .build();

HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
getRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
                    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest)) {
                        String headerContentType = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type").getValue();
                        if (headerContentType != null && headerContentType.contains("text/html")) {
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            if (entity != null) {
                                content = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");
                                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // log fail event here
                        }
                    }
```

Now I have `String content` as HTML content. 
I parse the content with `org.jsoup.Jsoup`.

```
    Document contentDoc = Jsoup.parse(
            content
    );
    String contentstr = contentDoc.body()
            .getElementsByTag("p")
            .text();
```

Comment: Could you provide example url

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak it is should be as robust as possible for any url. I prefer to apply 3rd party solution (use uBlock, AdsBlock library with some public filter list if possible) rather than do case-by-case for each url.

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak for example, this url https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/coronavirus-what-herd-immunity-how-21681418

Comment: I checked this page it has aside tag with class related-column secondary, and then js uploads content into this tag,so if you just crawl it then you won't have adv content
simple
Jsoup.connect will be enough